# sorting odd number in a new array, output problem

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

*to store odd numbers from a user inputed array(arr) in a new array(arr1), then printing.*
**run and see output first**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr1[100];
    int arr[5] = {2, 3, 8, 9, 11};
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 12; x++)
        {
            if (x == arr[i])
            {
                arr1[i] = arr[i];
            }
            x += 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "*run and see output first*". That's not how it works here. It is your responsibility to clearly explain the specific error or incorrect behaviour and to ask a specific question. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)` is off-by-one.

Comment: @Rudra Patole The provided code does not make a sense.

Comment: Suggest you learn to do basic debugging for yourself. Run your program in a debugger and/or add debugging print statements to trace the program execution. For example, check the value of `i` and `arr[i]` every time you hit the line `arr1[i] = arr[i];` and see if it is what you need it to be. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You incremented `x` twice, it would be more idiomatic to write `for (int x = 1; x < 12; x += 2)` but it is easier to test an odd number with `if(arr[i] % 2)`. The copying is flawed, though, because you are skipping elements of `arr1[]` (which remain uninitialised). You need another index variable for `arr1[]`.

Comment: @Rudra Patole To determine whether a number is odd it is enough to write if ( arr[i] % 2 != 0 ) { /*...*/}

Comment: yeah , two elements of `arr1[]` are getting garbage value.
tell me more about the another index variale for `arr1[]`

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks bro, i just got to know that %2 divides number by 2 and gives remainder if any , then we equate it with 0 or !0  to get even or odd number .

Comment: Do you mean storing and not sorting in title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if it is divisible by two using modulo operator `%`. If it is not divisible by 2 this should get `1`.
This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr1[100];
    int arr[5] = {2, 3, 8, 9, 11};
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (arr[i]%2 == 1) { //is odd
            arr1[j++] = arr[i];
        }

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```